# Formas de monetização em aplicativos

Tags: android, app

Quais são as formas de monetização em apps que vocês usam ?

E quais as mais fáceis de serem aplicadas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem 3 formas básicas de monetização:

- **Free**  (com anúncios)
- **Freemium** (com compras realizadas dentro do próprio App)
- **Pagos** (com um valor específico para realizar a instalação)

> [...]mais fáceis de serem aplicadas em meu app.

As 3 são relativamente fáceis. Talvez você não tenha que pensar qual é mais fácil ou não, mas qual seria mais viável para seu caso. Cada aplicação tem sua característica em relação a monetização dependendo do tipo de serviço que você irá oferecer. Tente identificar seu público alvo primeiro antes de monetizar. A implementação é a parte mais fácil de toda história.

Comment: como identificar esse público alvo?

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Leia esse artigo https://startupi.com.br/2014/09/nao-definir-um-publico-alvo-pode-ser-fatal-para-seu-app/